# How to Plot $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+(b-1)^2}{a^2+(b+1)^2}}=2$

Tags: analysis

How to plot this complex division?
$$
\sqrt{\frac{a^2+(b-1)^2}{a^2+(b+1)^2}}=2
$$

Answer (score 1):

The plot of $\sqrt{\frac{a^2+(b-1)^2}{a^2+(b+1)^2}}=2$ is the following:

[image]

Work out $a^2+(b-1)^2$ and $a^2+(b+1)^2$. This will give: 
$$\frac{a^2+(b-1)^2}{a^2+(b+1)^2} = \frac{1-4b}{a^2+b^2+2 b+1}$$

This would make it easier to solve.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. It's better if you post the picture directly.

Comment: Sorry, placed the picture.

Comment: Thats what i did, but i do not understand how they solved this equation, how they got the solution a=4/3 and b=-5/3

Comment: @user115961: Why not simplify your equation? You'll get an simple equation which represents the circle above.

Answer (score 1):

Squaring the given equality you can arrive at

$$a^2+b^2+\frac{10}{3}b+1=0. ~~(*)$$

Consider now the $(a,b)$-plane: can you recognize the locus of points which satisfy $(*)$?
Looking at its [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant_classification) you should be able to identify such locus as a circle.

To draw it, start to find the points of intersections with the coordinate axis, for example.